# Confusion matrix over multiple thresholds

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

I'm trying to (efficiently) run `sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix` for multiple thresholds. It needs to be done so that I can tell the customer what kind of performance one should expect at any given %challenge of the population.

Currently, I'm doing it in a loop, over all possible thresholds, but this is slow and inefficient. Any way to do it in a one-liner, or something similar?

```
threshold_list = (np.linspace(1, 0, 1001)).tolist()
for threshold in threshold_list:
    df.loc[df['score'] >= threshold,'prediction'] = '1'
    arr = confusion_matrix(df['true'].astype('int16').values, df['prediction'].astype('int16').values)
    ....
    ....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If TPr and FPr is enough for you. You can do the following:

```
y_true=[1,0,0,1,1,0,0]
y_pred=[0.67, 0.48, 0.27, 0.52, 0.63, 0.45, 0.53]
fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y_true, y_pred)
res = pd.DataFrame({'FPR': fpr, 'TPR': tpr, 'Threshold': thresholds})
res[['TPR', 'FPR', 'Threshold']]
```

Output:

```
    TPR         FPR Threshold
0   0.333333    0.00    0.67
1   0.666667    0.00    0.63
2   0.666667    0.25    0.53
3   1.000000    0.25    0.52
4   1.000000    1.00    0.27
```

Comment: Can definitely live with that. Thanks! :)